# ubuntu gnome short cut keys

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I have done something quite silly and not sure how to fix it.

I modified some of the gnome keyboard short cuts and was trying to disable the "Run Application" command. In the process I assigned it to the delete key and every time I hit delete the "Run Application" window comes up.

It would not normally be a problem but the "Keyboard Shortcuts" no long has the short cut in the window so I can't disable it.

Any help advice would be appreciated.

Cheers
Ben

Comment: It probably lives in GConf, but there are scary monsters in there. Good luck hunting. http://library.gnome.org/devel/gconf/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the way to do this is to go through the `Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`. There you can change any keyboard shortcut keys you have set, without necessarily having to go through `gconf-editor`.

Since you can't see the "Run Application", we have no choice but to mess with the gconf-edior.

Now, if you are willing and if you do actually wish to mess with the gconf-editor, do the following:

1. Open a terminal window and type `gconf-editor`.
2. Once you're in the application, [assuming you're familiar with the regedit in Windows] go to `apps \ metacity \ global_keybindings`.
3. You will notice a bunch of values to your right. Find and select (by "select" I mean "double-click") `panel_run_dialog` and a window titled "Edit Key" will pop-up. In your case, you should simply type "`<Alt>F2`" (without the double quotes of course) in the `Value` textbox.

This should fix your problem.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The entry reads "Show the panel's "Run Application" dialog box", and save royal screw-ups, there's no way to remove it. Click on the row, and as it reads on the bottom of the window, "press backspace to clear".